# Real coefficient linear phase FIR filter design based on least square

Tags: filters, filter-design, finite-impulse-response, linear-systems, digital-filters

I want to build up linear phase filter by least square approach.

I have formulated a least square problem similar to [Matt's blog](https://mattsdsp.blogspot.com/2022/10/fir-filters-with-prescribed-magnitude.html). To approximate the desired complex response $F \times 1 $ vector $d$ by the length $N$ FIR filter's , which coefficients are formed as $N \times 1 $ vector $h$. The basis $F \times N$ matrix $C$ and $F \times F $ weighting matrix $W$ is also deployed.

According to the [Rick's post](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/808.php#) the linear phase constraint can be formulated as

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}h(n)\sin((n- \frac{N-1}{2})\omega )
$$

the specified constraint can be transformed as $F \times N$ matrix $A$ in [this post](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/sasp/Least_Squares_Linear_Phase_FIR_Filter.html). This constraint is specified as a subproblem of the least square

$$
Ah = 0
$$

which homogeneous solution is $N \times N$ matrix $G = I - A^{+}A$. And $Gv = h$ is the solution of the subproblem. Therefore, the overall problem can be reformulated as

$$
\min_{v} |FGv - d|
$$

The answer is to find the $ h = Gv$. However, the $h$ I have already found still remains non-symmetric. How should I do about this problem? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: You don't need to impose a linear-phase constraint on the FIR coefficients. As long as the complex response $F$ is linear-phase (and causal, of course), the least squares method will give you a linear-phase solution.

Comment: You can (and probably should) formulate the problem as an approximation of a real-valued zero-phase response. In this way you directly design a linear phase filter, and the number of unknown coefficients is just (approx.) half the filter order. As an alternative, you can use the code from my blog and specify a linear desired phase (matching the chosen filter order). The optimal solution will be a linear phase filter (up to numerical accuracy), as suggested by @ZRHan.